# Is it possible to return data from a C# Class Library to a VBA module that called it? If so, what is the approach?

Tags: c#, vba, com

I am currently working with a VBA application that uses C# class libraries to extend their capabilities.  Until recently the data has flowed from VBA to the libraries and that was it.  Now, there is a need to hand data off to the library and have it return data to the calling VBA module.

I am not really sure how to approach the problem at this point.

As a specific use case.  The VBA app uses a collection provided by the C# DLL. The  VBA app creates the collection of items and sets a couple of properties on each element of the collection.  What is needed is to pass the collection down to C# and have it add to additional properties in the collection items.  Once the collection has been updated, hand it back to VBA for additional processing.

Is this even achievable?  Or is this not possible?

Comment: Check out [MSDN Consuming Unmanaged DLL Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions).

Comment: From what you say, yes it's possible. VBA and C# interop has full capacities. Try something and get back when you have concrete issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help and feedback.  Will see what we can accomplish and update here as things progress.